# opencv python detect ellipse egg-like shapes

Tags: python, opencv

i'm trying to detect ellipse egg-like shaped objects using opencv. color detection doesn't work properly in my case, because of different lighting angles. how would i be able to detect ellipse  egg-like shapes in a real world environment?

things i've tried so far:

- color detection (too many different lighting angles)
- contour matching
- calculating the form factor of the object

i can include my code if needed, but i don't think it will add much value.

Comment: Could you provide sample images?

Comment: Have you tried color detection in different colorspaces? Color range thresholds are a little non-intuitive to set up.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ellipse detection in opencv python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42206042/ellipse-detection-in-opencv-python)